# force VS Code to get typescript from path

Tags: typescript

I am totally confused about typescript installation; I have  installed  typescript in /microsoft SDKs/typescript/1.8 ;  I set path as C://programfiles(86x)/microsoftSDK/typescript/1.8
when I use nodejs  tsc --version  from any location  I get 2.5.2
but in VS Code when I run the same command I get 1.0.3.0
how can I force VS Code to us version 2.5.2 because I want to use decorator

Answer (score 1):

The [official documentation says](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/typescript#_using-newer-typescript-versions)...

> To use a different TypeScript version by default, configure
>   typescript.tsdk in your user settings to point to a directory
>   containing the TypeScript tsserver.js file. You can find the
>   TypeScript installation location using npm list -g typescript. The
>   tsserver.js file is usually in the lib folder.

So for most people, installing the latest version of TypeScript with NPM will mean VSCode uses that latest version:

```
npm install -g typescript
```

But you can get the location of the `tsserver.js` file by running:

```
npm list -g typescript
```

Add the path it returns to your user settings in VSCode, like this:

```
{
   "typescript.tsdk": "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib"
}
```

Or, of course, point it to another version elsewhere if you want to.

Comment: thanks but your answer needs and expert to understand it; can you please explain exactly how do I use tsc version 2.5.2 which I have installed in Program Files(86x)/Microsof SDKs/Typescript/1.8   and have accordingly set %Path%  in visual Code.

Comment: I did the following: 
C:\Users\user\express-ts\app\controllers>npm install -g typescript
C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\tsc -> C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_
modules\typescript\bin\tsc
C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\tsserver -> C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\
node_modules\typescript\bin\tsserver
C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm
`-- typescript@2.5.3


{
"window.zoomLevel": 2,
"typescript.tsdk":
"users/user/AppDat/roaming/npm/node-modules/typescript/bin/"
}